# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to get the first column in the first row of my result set. I know I can change my SQL query to do that. BUT no. I want the full table and I only want to do what I just mentioned.

**NOTE - Winners is an Aliased column in my sql query.**

The error is basically -

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
The result set has no current row.
```

More of the error -

```
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetHasCurrentRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:483)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getterGetColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:2047)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2082)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:2067)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getString(SQLServerResultSet.java:2401)
```

This is what I have tried so far and I need your help to fix it -

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("get a whole table"); //pseudocode

try{            
    rs.next();
    numberOne = rs.getString("Winners");
    rs.first(); 
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is probably nothing in your result set. Use

```
if (rs.next()) {
    numberOne = rs.getString("Winners");
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats strange. How can there be nothing in my result set ? I have executed the same query in my database and I get results. But java fails :(

Comment: Either you're not pointing to the same database or schema, or you've not committed the transaction used to insert the rows.

Comment: I ran the same query on SQL server which my ResultSet uses. It works fine. Don't know why this does not work in Java. Commit is not a problem, DB is loaded with rows. I only need to read DB and not write to DB.

Comment: I used the CachedRowSetImpl along with the irritating ResultSet. Now, it works.

Comment: This is completely broken... I have something in my ResultSet but can only use it, when I place `rs.beforeFirst(); rs.next();` in front of `rs.getSomething();`... Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?